# Regex for positive float numbers

Tags: regex

**For example:**
10
0.1
1.23234
123.123
0.000001
1.000
.3

**And wrong examples:**
0001.2
-12
-1.01
+2.3

**EDIT:** standart JavaScript regex.

Comment: With which regular expression engine?

Comment: what's wrong with `(int) $value > 0`? (or the equivalent in your language)

Comment: also, to get picky with your examples, what happens in the following cases: `0.0`, `0`, etc? And is a plus sign allowed, eg `+4.12`? Finally, most of your examples are fairly small numbers: are there any range constraints on how big (or small) it can be, or the number of decimal places, and so on?

Comment: Spudley, I need to build mask for grid column. No limits for length of number and decimal places.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this here

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tpce)

If matching the empty string is not wanted, then you can add a length check to your regex like

```
^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

The positive lookahead `(?=.+)` ensures that there is at least 1 character

Comment: This also matches the empty string (which might or might not be desirable).

Comment: @stema can you modify it to allow like this --> 12.230.45

Comment: Its allowing 10.10.1 value

Comment: To exclude zero value (e.g 0, 0.00, 0.00000, 00.00), use this modified regex:
`^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*)?(?:(\.\d+)|(0\.\d*[1-9]+\d*))?$`

Answer (score 9):

This will pass all your test cases, multi-line mode enabled:

```
/^(?!0\d)\d*(\.\d+)?$/mg
```

Explanation:

```
/^              # start of regex and match start of line
(?!0\d)         # not any number with leading zeros
\d*             # consume and match optional digits
(\.\d+)?        # followed by a decimal and some digits after, optional.
$               # match end of line
/mg             # end of regex, match multi-line, global match
```

**RegExr:** http://regexr.com?2tpd0

Comment: ...and the empty string, too.

Comment: Might be possible to fix not matching an empty string with `^(((?!00)\d*)(\.\d+)?){1}$`

Answer (score 5):

**Consider the regular expression:**

```
^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
```

This regular expression will matches floating point number like:

```
 - .343
 - 0.0
 - 1.2
 - 44
 - 44.
 - 445.55
 - 56.
 - . //Only dot(.) also matches
 - empty string also matches
```

The above regular expression will will not accept:

```
- h32.55 //Since ^ is used. So, the match must start at the beginning
   of the string or line.
- 23.64h //Since $ is used. So, the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.
```

**Consider the regular expression:**

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

This regular expression will matches floating point number like:

```
 - 45
 - 45.5
 - 0.0
 - 1.2
 - 445.55
```

This regular expression will not accept:

```
 - h32.55 //Since ^ is used. So, the match must start at the beginning
   of the string or line. 
 - 23.64h //Since $ is used. So, the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.
 - 44. 
 - . //Only dot(.) does not matches here
 - empty string also does not matches here
```

**Pure floating point:**

```
^(([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?))$
```

- You can check the regular expression [here](http://regexr.com/).
- Refer MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled on this page a few times, here is my solution for any one who stumbles here after me:

A regex like a=(\d+\.?\d* | \d*\.?\d+) matches all decimals numbers without a sign but includes things like 002.0

A regex to filter those things are b=[1-9\.]+.*

So one solution is to say it matches the criteria if a & b matches. Or equivalently (contrapositive), see if there is no match for !a | !b. Unfortunately, most languages don't have a complete regex package; the 'and' and negate functions of regular languages isn't present usually. Two simple regexes I've found in code looks a lot nicer and are more maintainable than one complex one (I say this in context to this question & similar situations)