# How can I validate number between 1 and 99 using regular expression?

Tags: regex

What is regular expression so that user can enter any integer or float number between 1-99.

For entering only integer I know regular expression is:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Please tell me RE for entering integer as well as float numbers between 1-99.

Comment: @Asad I think OP want's also for FLOAT.

Comment: Just check if the number is between 1.0 to 99.0 , possible both at backend as well as frontend ( javascript )

Comment: @DhruvPathak And you know this user is making this for a web client how..?

Comment: @Daedalus No matter that the app language is, if it supports regex, it must be supporting simple comparison of floats IMHO.I do not know of a use case where regex is a better choice to check if a number lies in a range.

Comment: @DhruvPathak I agree with you there, I just don't see where you got javascript from.

Comment: @Daedalus that was an example, may be I framed my comment incorrectly.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate. [This question is about validating a float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029674/regex-for-positive-float-numbers), but for checking a number range, regex is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple version is `^[1-9][0-9]?$` for integers and `^([1-8][0-9]?|9[0-8]?)\.\d+$` for floats. If you want one for both: `^(([1-8][0-9]?|9[0-8]?)\.\d+|[1-9][0-9]?)$`

Test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/Zt8p8b7zyE)

Comment: ^(([1-8][0-9]?|9[0-8]?)\.\d+|[1-9][0-9]?)$ is working fine.<br/> THANKS GUYS.............

Answer (score 0):

Try [1-9][0-9]?(.[0-9]*)?

Edit: The above include 99.something too. This shouldn't:

```
[1-9](([0-8](\.[0-9]*)?)|[0-9])?
```

Test it [here](http://regexpal.com/), it works. ;)

Comment: Doesn't.  Matches 99.5, which is above 99.