# How to perform inline validation in Knockout on an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to allow the user to only enter postive numbers and numbers less then 100.
How can i modify this input markup to get my required validation.

```
<input data-bind="value : $root.rootData.Page" class="form-control">
```

Edit: I know i can validate in JS, but for my particular case i want to do it solely in the  makrup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with HTML5 using the pattern attribute.

[How can I validate number between 1 and 99 using regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171887/how-can-i-validate-number-between-1-and-99-using-regular-expression) - Will give you some information about different ways to check if a number is between 1 and 99

From your example, you could use the following

```
<input data-bind="value : $root.rootData.Page" class="form-control" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]?$">
```

Comment: if it's a numeric field/value, why not just use the number type?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using regex to match a number field, why not just use the number type and provide min/max?

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" data-bind="value : $root.rootData.Page" class="form-control" />
```

Regex could be used in combination with number type as a fallback, since FF support for the number type is lacking:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]?$" data-bind="value : $root.rootData.Page" class="form-control" />
```