# Regexp for a float literal

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for a decimal float literal that

- Does not match integer literal

  - `123` is invalid
- Does not require a number in front of the dot

  - `.123` is valid
- Requires a number after the dot

  - `1.` is invalid
  - `1.1` is valid
- Allows underscore anywhere but in the first position

  - `.1_2` is valid
  - `_.12` is invalid
  - `1_2.0` is valid
- Allows an exponent indicator

  - `1e2` is valid
  - `1.1e2` is valid

Note that this is a not a duplicate [Regex for positive float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029674/regex-for-positive-float-numbers) because that question does not mention the exponential part of the float, which adds a significant amount of complexity to the answer

Comment: How about `12.e3`? `1_2_3_4`? `1___2`? Is there any grammar for these literals?

Comment: @thg435 I see no reason why the examples with underscores wouldn't be valid, except that they are integer literals. The question is edited to address your first point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since individual each element of the regexp is simple and straightforward, here are their definitions:

- integer portion is `[0-9][0-9_]*`
- decimal portion is `\.[0-9][0-9_]*`
- exponent portion is `[eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*`

Next, the valid and invalid groupings are enumerated:

```
|int|dec|exp|->|valid|
|===|===|===|==|=====|
| no| no| no|->| no  |
| no| no|yes|->| no  |
| no|yes| no|->| yes |
| no|yes|yes|->| yes |
|yes| no| no|->| no  |
|yes| no|yes|->| yes |
|yes|yes| no|->| yes |
|yes|yes|yes|->| yes |
```

A few duplicate regexps are not too bad, but 12 duplications are a few too many. This can be fixed by simplifying the table to the most minimal form possible:

```
|int|dec|exp|->|valid|
|===|===|===|==|=====|
|yes| ? |yes|->| yes |
| ? |yes| ? |->| yes |
```

The `?`s signify that whether that expression is there or not, the match is still valid.

Substituting in the sub-regexps:

```
# Row 1
(?:[0-9][0-9_]*+)
(?:\.[0-9][0-9_]*)?
(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*)

| # Row 2
(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)?
(?:\.[0-9][0-9_]*)
(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*)?
```

which, if you enjoy obfuscated code, can also be written like

```
(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:\.[0-9][0-9_]*)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*)|(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)?(?:\.[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*)?
```