# How to fix this regexp to exclude negative numbers

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

This one match some unnessasary values like following.

```
$("#orderNumber").inputFilter(function(value) {
        return /^\d*[.]?\d*$/.test(value); });
```

I would like to get rid of it. How can i do that?
Exclude negative numbers -13, -15.372, first dot like .375, last symbol dot - 123.
I would like to get this result:

1.375 - match
135 - match

Only positive numbers with dot.

Comment: Remove the `-?` from the very start of the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, the old one pattern

Comment: can you please clarify your question

Comment: @Tausif, i would like to forbid numbers like ".03" and "33."  where the dot in the edge.

Comment: I think you are looking for `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/Aes892/1

Comment: No need to post any answers, validating int/float numbers is a beaten path. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609228/3832970) is the answer (`/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? '*' means any number of matches so 0 or more, while '+' means 1 or more.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: `^\d+[.]?\d+$` is a very  wrong pattern since it does not allow single digit numbers.

Comment: Now, `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` is equal to an already [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609228/3832970), please consider removing the post as there is no need duplicating SO contents.