# Regular expression for non-zero positive floats

Tags: javascript, regex

[Regex for positive float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029674/regex-for-positive-float-numbers) provides almost the correct expressions, but all of them include `0.0` and `0`.  Closest desired expression is:  `^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$` but this includes `0.0` and `0`.

What is the regex expression for positive floating numbers such as:

```
1.0
1.1
0.1
11
```

but do not include floating numbers such as:

```
0.0
-0.0
0
-1.0
-1.1
-0.1
-11
```

Comment: Add `(?!0\.0$)` after `^`

Comment: Would this be filter out `0`s with trailing `0`s?  Such as `0.000000`?

Comment: You might also use an alternation to match either variation `^(?:[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?|0+\.0*[1-9]\d*)$` https://regex101.com/r/G8DhCV/1

Comment: Do you mean a float in theory (you know where there is infinite possibility), or a float as in a string you can parse in JavaScript and get back a positive number from? I'm talking about numbers like 0.000000000000000000000000000000000001. This is theoretically a positive float, but will give you 0 if you try to parse it. If you are talking about the former, then using a regular expression is the right way to go about it. But if precision and the limitations of a float number as exists in JavaScript matter, then the answer is that you should skip the regex and just use parseFloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0(?!(?:\.0+)?$))?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/WApvZ7/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0                        '0'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the
                                 most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Your answer approves `'.0'` and `''`

Answer (score 1):

This one is the best:

```
^\.0*[1-9]\d*$|^0(\.0*[1-9]\d*)$|^[1-9]\d*?(\.\d+)?$
```

See how it works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iUIdtK/1).

If you don't want to accept floats like `.5`, use this one:

```
^0(\.0*[1-9]\d*)$|^[1-9]\d*?(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from the linked question can be adapted by removing the choice of `0` from the first group, and choosing between that group and another group that starts with 0.

```
^(((?:[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?)|(0\.[1-9]\d*))$
```

This works too:

```
^((([1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?)|(0\.[1-9]\d*))$
```

Basically, this is "saying" that if the number starts with 0, it has to be followed by a dot and something *other* than 0. After that, any digit is permissible. So, 0 and 0.0 aren't permitted, but 0.1 and 0.10 are.

**Note:** This Regex will not permit leading 0s. So, for example 101.0 is permissible but 0101.0 is not.

**Edit:** The following will allow for cases like 0.01:

```
^((([1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?)|(0\.[1-9]\d*)|(0\.0+[1-9]+\d*))$
```

Comment: 'Basically, this is "saying" that if the number starts with 0, it has to be followed by a dot and something other than 0.'

Hm, wouldn't that mean 0.01 would be invalid?